# Files corrupted when moved from internal memory

Tags: storage, lg, device-firmware, data-corruption

I've been using an LG Q60 since May. Occasionally spot a few pics and videos that won't play. Assume corrupted.
Updated it to Android 10 last week and since then I can't transfer files from the phone's internal storage to the sd card. All files are corrupted during the move. Compressing files with winrar fails too.

Can anybody advise on a fix?

Comment: How to you perform the file operations (what program, command, or whatever)?

Comment: I use file manager

Comment: The built-in file manager or a third party app from Play Store?

Comment: Both the built in and third party apps

Comment: guess your MicroSD Card is corrupt. buy new one and try again